# Send reply-to param in airflow emailoperator

Tags: airflow, mwaa

I am sending mail using airflow emailOperator. Is there any way to send "reply-to" parameter also. i tried `default_param={'key':'value'}` but throwing exception as invalid parameter.
I read this https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/operators/email.py
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/tests/operators/test_email.py
But I don't know where i am doing mistake.
version : 2.0.2

```
email_op = EmailOperator(
            task_id='send_email',
            to=destination['emails'],
            subject=destination['subject'],
            html_content=destination['message'],
            files=[file.name],
            default_param={'Reply-To': 'reply_to@example.com'},
        )
 email_op.execute(context)
```

Comment: It's `custom_headers` not `default_param`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be passed via dictionary `custom_headers`, as per the [Official Source Code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/operators/email.py) and [Official Docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/email/index.html)

I actually took the `Reply-To` directly from the [official Airflow unit test](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/tests/utils/test_email.py).

**There was a bug** patched in [release 2.3.0](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/release_notes.html) with the send_email function to correctly pass the custom_headers. This might be your root cause...

- Here is the [link to the issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16740)
- Here is the [pull request to resolve it](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/19009)

For new comers here is how you would send the custom_headers when using 2.3.0 and above.

```
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator

t1 = EmailOperator(
    task_id='send_email',
    to="email@example.com",
    subject="Airflow Example",
    html_content=""" <h3>Email Test</h3> """,
    cc="email@example",
    custom_headers = {
        'Reply-To': 'reply_to@example.com'
    }
)
```