# Change "reply-to" for Airflow email notifications?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

We have email notifications set up for Airflow. When a dag fails, we get an email alert but the email from is set to : `airflow@mycompany.com`

We would like to modify the `reply-to` in these cases to be `person@mycompany.com`. Is this possible?

Note, we are *not* using EmailOperator or any user-defined send_email/oncallback functions, just the built-in alerting.
It seems EmailOperator, you can pass in "custom_headers" with reply-to argument ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73768320/send-reply-to-param-in-airflow-emailoperator)) but we are not using emailoperator.

Airflow 2.2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per this discussion: https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/30684

Write a Python function that wraps for `send_email_smtp` and handles custom headers and then reference it in config file here.

```
# Configuration email backend and whether to
# send email alerts on retry or failure
# Email backend to use
email_backend = airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp
```

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/utils/email.py

I've not implemented yet but that seems to be the approach.

See also SendGrid's email implementation:

- [https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/email-config.html#:~:text=AIRFLOW__EMAIL__EMAIL_BACKEND%3D-,airflow.providers.sendgrid.utils.emailer.send_email,-AIRFLOW__EMAIL__EMAIL_CONN_ID%3Dsendgrid_default](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/email-config.html#:%7E:text=AIRFLOW__EMAIL__EMAIL_BACKEND%3D-,airflow.providers.sendgrid.utils.emailer.send_email,-AIRFLOW__EMAIL__EMAIL_CONN_ID%3Dsendgrid_default)
- https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-sendgrid/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/sendgrid/utils/emailer.html#send_email